# jQuery .before and .after not behaving as expected

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML code

```
<p><img src="src.jpg" clas="left" title="image title text"></p>
```

And the following jQuery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('img').each(function() {
        var t = $(this).attr('title'),
            c = $(this).attr('class'),
            w = $(this).width();
        $(this).before('<div class="caption ' + c + '">');
        $(this).after(t + '</div>');
    });
});
```

However the output that this is giving me is as below

```
<p><div class="caption left"></div>
<img src="src.jpg" clas="left" title="image title text">
image title text</p>
```

I can not for the life of me see why the open and close of the DIV happens before when I specify the closing tag in the .after section. I bet it is super basic but I just can not see it. Any help is massively appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: You will probably find it easier to just insert in `$(this).parent()` rather than (mis)use `.before()` and `.after()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only add elements to the document, not tags. When the HTML code for the page is parsed, the starting and end tags end up as a single element object in the DOM.

When you try to add the starting tag, the browser will add an ending tag to complete it. When you try to end the ending tag, it will just be ignored. (At least in the browser that you are using. Behaviour might differ for other browsers.)

To wrap an element around another, use the [`wrap` method](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) or [`wrapAll` method](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/):

```
$(this).wrapAll('<div class="caption ' + c + '"></div>').after(t);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JR4j3/

Comment: Thanks loads, this was incredibly helpful and makes a lot of sense now that I was using those tags incorrectly. Works perfectly now! Just got to get the styles sorted.

Answer (score 1):

You can't open a div without closing it.

Or the proper way to say it: You can't open a element with `before` (or any kind of appending operator) without closing it with the same operation.

So that means you can't have a `.before('<div>')` and after that a `.after('</div>')`.

For this you can use [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

Answer (score 0):

This is just the way this works.  You are inserting invalid HTML before the element using the .before() function.  A div element without a closing tag is invalid and the browser will automatically append a closing tag to try to fix the issue.

Instead of using .before() and .after(), have a look at the .wrap() method.